# Change the style of the border in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a chart using Chart.js library. I want border of this chart to be dotted, not solid. Can someone help me please?

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: '#ffec87',
      borderWidth: 0,
      borderStyle: 'dotted'
    }]
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="100px"></canvas>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you describe what full-width is?

Comment: Full width is solid line

Comment: Which lines are you referring to; the x or y axis?

Comment: I want y axis border to remove and x axis border to be dotted

Comment: thanks a lot! I appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Styling docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#grid-line-configuration) list all the config options for axis grid line configuration.

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: '#ffec87',
      borderWidth: 0,
      borderStyle: 'dotted'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxis: { grid: { display: false } },
      yAxis: { grid: { borderDash: [8, 4] } }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="100px"></canvas>
```